# error: no matching member function for call to 'reset' (shared pointers)

Tags: c++, pointers, makefile, initialization, shared-ptr

```
template<typename T>
struct Node{
      ListNode(SkipListKind kind, const T& key);
      std::shared_ptr<ListNode<T>> next;
}
```

A shared pointer to a Node has been initialized (call it node) and it's next member variable has been set to NULL.

```
node->next.reset(std::make_shared<ListNode<T>>(SkipListKind::PosInf, T{}));
```

Error:
error: no matching member function for call to 'reset' (shared pointers)

In terms of type:
std::shared_ptr>.reset(std::make_shared>)

I am using .reset because the pointer originally points to NULL.
Why am I getting this error?
Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `swap` instead, or use assignment. `reset` takes a raw pointer.

Answer (score 1):

`std::shared_ptr::reset()` function required a raw pointer as parameter.

You can use assignment operator to resolve your issue:

```
node->next = std::make_shared<ListNode<T>>(SkipListKind::PosInf, T{}));
```

If you prefer swap do as follows:

```
std::make_shared<ListNode<T>>(SkipListKind::PosInf, T{}).swap(node->next);
```

Comment: The `std::move` is completely redundant, `make_shared` returns an rvalue so it will be move-assigned anyway. And you can't swap with an rvalue on the right-hand-side, you would need to do `make_shared<ListNode<T>>(...).swap(node->next)`